# Change (or add) background color in VS Code when renaming from Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the image below I'm actually in "rename" and I'm highlighting something but there's no highlight. You'll notice there's no cursor as well because it's highlighting. This is driving me a bit bonkers because I'm either counting how many left/right arrow keys I'm moving and such to know where I am. I tried the following colors but none of these seem to do anything (in the Explorer):

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorRuler.foreground": "#fc199a22",
    "editor.selectionBackground": "#ab3beb3f",
    "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#136460e3",
    "editor.findMatchBackground": "#00cc44a8",
    "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#d0ff004d",
    "scrollbarSlider.background": "#FC199A2c"
},
```

I tried inspecting the element in the developer console in VS Code but the rename closes when it blurs out of the field which I need to do to select the element to know what the CSS class is to style it.

I didn't see a "rename" or highlight color for the explorer here either: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors

Any help would be super appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following property:

```
"selection.background" : "#FF0"
```

> The background color of text selections in the workbench (e.g. for input fields or text areas). Note that this does not apply to selections within the editor.

A caveat to this approach is that it is applied globally, not just the explorer view

[image: selection image]

Comment: No problem; is that theme widely used @OscarGodson It doesn't feel right to override a global setting like that in my opinion, at least to the point where it's not even recognizable that you are highlighting something.

Comment: It's a fairly popular theme I think. It's https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=webrender.synthwave-x-fluoromachine which is heavily based on https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobbOwen.synthwave-vscode

Comment: Ah that makes sense, it requires Custom CSS and JS Loader. It may have it's own configuration or setting for this, I'll take a peek, but that doesn't feel right in my opinion. That setting I provided applies to *all* inputs not just when renaming, and it's the only one; I'm just thinking how that could be a problem for accessability and people who rely on accessability features. thanks

Comment: Ah yes, their custom CSS for inputs: `.monaco-inputbox>.wrapper>textarea.input::selection {
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}` that's a 0.3 transparency. Interesting choice for a dark puprle background. I guess if 250,000 people don't mind it what ya going to do @OscarGodson

Comment: Most likely they have installed the Theme, tried it and didn't liked it and choose a different one ;-) It's only 20K installs